# MongoDB after Power Outage

Tags: mongodb

I am running mongoDB on a local appliance machine, with journaling enabled.

Is it always guaranteed that mongo will recover itself automatically even on power outage(meaning that the database was not closed properly) when journaling is enabled?

On what scenarios MongoDB will be corrupted even if journaling is enabled(besides filesystem corruption)?

Comment: This is rather a question for http://dba.stackexcgange.com. Voted to close, as DO is dedicated to programming related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed (assuming no filesystem corruption):

> With journaling enabled, MongoDB creates a journal subdirectory within the directory defined by dbPath, which is /data/db by default. The journal directory holds journal files, which contain write-ahead redo logs. The directory also holds a last-sequence-number file. A clean shutdown removes all the files in the journal directory. **A dirty shutdown (crash) leaves files in the journal directory; these are used to automatically recover the database to a consistent state when the mongod process is restarted.**

([Journaling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/) /core/journaling in the manual)

This is a big point for journaling in the first place and one of the primary reason journaling is used. Note data will still likely be lost (from the last 100ms or so) but the DB will be in a consistent state.

Comment: @Transcendence yes yes we all love ourselves some Mongo bashing, spare me the "Web Scale" link. What mongo claimed and turned out to be false was mostly complex use cases involving clusters, sharding and replication - unlike dealing consistency with byzantine failures on big clusters with lots of reads and writes, just restoring to a consistent state from a journal is definitely something Mongo can do.

Comment: From my experience, the data loss is more like 50ms (median) with 100ms being the rare worst case. As always for database servers, they should be backed by an independent power supply, anyway. Everything else is negligent, improper and unprofessional, making the question kind of academic and a bit pointless.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg it's not pointless, I definitely agree overall, I've never actually seen 100ms data loss when I tested it but it's what the engine guarantees so it's the bound I'm giving. It goes without saying that things should be backed up and replicated but I'm guessing OP is using Mongo as client-side storage here (to back up a desktop app for instance) rather than as a DB server (a la Mongo as SQLite) so I wouldn't go as far as calling it "improper and unprofessional" if your save-game or settings or other client-side stuff has a 100ms delay. Still a much stronger guarantee than files.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Not backing core services with an independent power supply? C'mon, that goes without saying pretty much as backups do, doesn't it? My point is that the journaling feature should be the last line of defense against data corruption  (the others being an independent power supply and a journaling FS), not the only one (which imho would be unprofessional). Other than that, I wholeheartedly agree with you.